# Laravel API MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, jwt, restful-authentication

I'm using Laravel 5.4 as an API. I have a routes set up for login and registration like so:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::put('user', 'Auth\AuthController@changeUserName');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegistration');
```

trying to login or register I create a post request with the required input I'm supposed to get 200 success response along with a JWT authorization header. And that works very well on my local machine: (Fedora 25, Apache/2.4.25, PHP 7.0.15) However on my production server (Ubuntu 14.04, Apache/2.4.7, PHP 7.1.2-3) I'm getting the above error.

Note of course that it's the same exact code. (I re-cloned the project just to be sure).

Comment: Try to reset caches. Smth like `artisan route:clear`

Comment: unfortunately that does not help. I even deleted the project and recloned it :(

Comment: The only point where Laravel seems to throw that exception is when you're trying to access a registered route under a different Http Method. Check the response header, there should be an `Allow` header to say which methods are allowed.

Comment: postman says `allow →POST` which exactly is the method I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the problem was I was posting in `http://` but I set up let's encrypt and made it redirect my requests automatically to https. but I don't think that works with post requests.

So when I prefixed `https://` to my url everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **http://** to **https://**

works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).